# Sphinx Search Cron Issue

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cron, sphinx

I am trying to use the Sphinx main + delta system with Sphinx. I got everything working except for the Cron job keeps on saying `WARNING: no such index 'listings_delta_index', skipping` from the log. When I manually run the command it works just fine. The command I am running and the sphinx.conf I am using is below. I also tried changing the index name to listings_index and that doesn't work either.

**Sphinx.conf**

```
source listings_source
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = user2
    sql_pass        = password
    sql_db          = MyVirtuals
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
    sql_query_pre   = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre   = REPLACE INTO sph_counter SELECT 1, MAX(listing_id) FROM     listings
    sql_query_pre   = REPLACE INTO sph_last_index SELECT 1, NOW()
    sql_query       = \
    SELECT listing_id, title,CRC32(mainCategoryID) as mainCategoryID,CAST(price AS DECIMAL(12,2)) as price, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created) AS date_created, description \
    FROM listings WHERE listing_id<=(SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1) AND status = 1
    sql_query_killlist  = SELECT listing_id FROM listings WHERE modified_on >= (SELECT last_reindex_on FROM sph_last_index WHERE counter_id=1)

    sql_attr_timestamp  = date_created
    sql_attr_uint   = mainCategoryID
    sql_attr_float  = price

    #sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id=$id
}
index listings_index
{
    source      = listings_source
    path        = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/listings_index
    docinfo     = extern
    charset_type    = sbcs
    min_word_len    = 1
    html_strip      = 1
}
source listings_delta_source : listings_source{
    sql_query_pre       = SET NAMES utf8
    #Pull listings that are new and changed
    sql_query       = SELECT listing_id, title, CRC32(mainCategoryID) as mainCategoryID, CAST(price AS DECIMAL(12,2)) as price, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created) AS date_created, description \
    FROM listings WHERE listing_id>(SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1) OR modified_on >= (SELECT last_reindex_on FROM sph_last_index WHERE counter_id=1)
}
index listings_delta_index : listings_index{

        source      = listings_delta_source
        path        = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/listings_delta_index
        docinfo     = extern
        charset_type    = sbcs
        min_word_len    = 1
        html_strip      = 1
}
indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 32M
}
searchd
{
    listen      = 9312
    listen      = 9306:mysql41
    log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
    query_log       = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
    read_timeout    = 5
    max_children    = 30
    pid_file        = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
    max_matches     = 1000
    seamless_rotate = 1
    preopen_indexes = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    workers     = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path     = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data
}
```

**sphinx_update_delta.sh**

```
indexer -c /var/www/scripts-conf/sphinx.conf --rotate listings_delta_index
```

**crontab**

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report     /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
*/1 *    * * *   root    sh /var/www/scripts-conf/sphinx_update_delta.sh > /var/log/cronlog.log
*  0    * * *   root    sh /var/www/scripts-conf/sphinx_update_main.sh
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: How are you running it from the command line? By executing the shell script or manually? Are you using the exact same config?

Comment: I am running the .sh file from the crontab. I will edit my post to include the crontab file.

Comment: But I'm asking when you test it manually are you using the exact same command?

Comment: I am running it manually not the script file itself. Would that cause a permissions issue or something?

Comment: No it shouldn't matter and permissions issue should just fail. What I was thinking was you might have two copies of the config and the paths were getting crossed up.

Comment: But for fun try running the shell script (with sudo) ... see if it does anything differently

Comment: also as your own user do `which indexer` and then actually become root (sudo su -) and do `which indexer` make sure those match

Comment: Yes they match. I get the same error when I run the script manually from the command line. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: It shouldn't cause it but if you run the command directly you are most likely running it with bash but cron is running it with sh. Try putting it in your own crontab (`crontab -e` as your own user). Set `SHELL=/bin/bash` and add the command with sudo

Comment: Still didn't work. Very annoying.

Comment: Just to ask the obvious, is "/var/www/scripts-conf/sphinx.conf" definitly the config file you've posted above.

Comment: Yes it is. When I run the command manually from the AWS EC2 Java Shell it works perfectly. When I run the commands from a .sh file by the shell and by the crontab they don't work. What could I be doing wrong or what should I change?

Comment: Try adding --verbose to the command line in the .sh file. That will hopefully show you path to the config file its actully using. Is it the same as the one you expect?

Comment: What version of sphinx is it?

Comment: Sphinx 2.0.6-release (r3473)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indexer -c /var/www/scripts-conf/sphinx.conf --rotate listings_delta_index

sphinx.conf is lowercase

in your first block you write as title Sphinx.conf (not sphinx.conf)

---

tips

```
sh /var/www/scripts-conf/sphinx_update_delta.sh > /var/log/cronlog.log
```

replace the  *>* by *| tee*

```
sh /var/www/scripts-conf/sphinx_update_delta.sh | tee /var/log/cronlog.log
```

to view result on manually run